# fresh install, update and x-windows no longer working after login 12.10

Tags: 12.10

I Just recently installed desktop 12.10 on laptop, all was working fine logged in and it stated it wanted to update as it found updates.

naturally I let it update and it asked me to reboot to use the new updates

did that, now it boots fine i get login prompt.
login as per normal
then all i get is background with nothing else, if i turn off the wireless i get the disconnection notification pop up but i have nothing else on screen any wrror messages gets displayed as well but their is nothing.

their was one program that failed that no longer prompts which gives options of reloading or just closing and continuing either way it just look like it hangs I can ctrl alt del to log out and it does that fine but still wont load no mater how many times i try

saw a topic about a ati driver playing up which he typed the following in a ty which i can get to all of them as well.

export DISPLAY=:0;gnome-shell --replace

the answer i got back was the program gnome-shell is not installed you can install it by typing sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

i also tried sudo pkill X which did nothing

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Gnome shell was not installed - installed gnome-shell and this has not made any difference to the issue.

I have looked into this as my machine was running while unattended i saw that there was an error that could have something to do with this issue.  The error goes as follows:  System program problem detected  The application Compiz has closed unexpectedly  /usr/bin/compiz  Compiz-core 1:0.9.8.4+bzr3407-0ubuntu1  Crash  Compiz crashed with sigsegv in xcb_glx_get_string_string_length()  
I uninstalled the gnome-shell as I wanted to revert back to original interface GUI  then Uninstalled the compiz-core (sudo apt-get remove compiz-core)  I re-installed compiz-core (sudo apt-get install compiz-core)  rebooting to check outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System program problem detected

The application Compiz has closed unexpectedly 
/usr/bin/compiz 
Compiz-core 1:0.9.8.4+bzr3407-0ubuntu1 
Crash 
Compiz crashed with sigsegv in xcb_glx_get_string_string_length() 
I uninstalled the gnome-shell as I wanted to revert back to original interface GUI 
then Uninstalled the compiz-core (sudo apt-get remove compiz-core) 
I re-installed compiz-core (sudo apt-get install compiz-core) 
rebooting to check outcome 
this initially didn't fix the issue. 
i also completed the following: 
pressed CTRL + ALT + T after logging in to bring up terminal window and typed the following: 
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge gnome-themes-standard 
and 
sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard

the above seemed to have fixed the issue.